# I can not see the Server option in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I can not see the Server option in eclipse, when I go to Windows-->showview, even in the --Others--option it's not there. I am using eclipse luna. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded a package that doesn't include the server/web features. Instead, [download](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/mars1) **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**.